# Ipconfig and Network Connection status shows different things on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, ipconfig

I've this weird situation where `ipconfig /all` shows all dns-es for LAN connection correctly, however when I go to network properties of this LAN connection and check status it only shows 2 ip address (always not showing 127.0.0.1).

```
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.16(Preferred)
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.16
                                     127.0.0.1
                                     192.168.1.17
 Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.16
 Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 192.168.1.17
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

If i then go to checking configuration (or doing any modifications) I can clearly see there settings are correct. This wouldn't be a big deal but BPA for DNS on this server is complaining that loopback address isn't added to DNS list and I want to clean it up from errors.

Comment: Have you looked on the DNS tab of the Advanced TCP/IP Settings of the IPv4 protocol?

Comment: Yes, the settings are there. They are visible without problem. My collegue right now removed 1.16 from the list and moved .1.17 to the top and left 127.0.0.1 as second entry and BPA stopped complaining but still status only shows 192.168.1.17 as DNS server skipping to show 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the machine you're running the commands on is an Active Directory Domain Controller and/or DNS server, I believe it automatically hardcodes `127.0.0.1` (i.e., the local host) as a valid source for DNS information.

Comment: If only you can give me some reference for that so that I can assume it's normal for Status to not show 127.0.0.1 I would be happy :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I have no proof of this behavior, it just seems to be that way in my experience.

Comment: Is your domain controller also hiding 127.0.0.1 even thou it's entered as DNS server? (in the connection status graphical interface).

Comment: Yes, it is. It also hides the "::1" IPv6 version of localhost, which in my case is visible from `ipconfig`.